# Enable newsletter subscription for orders placed in the backend

Tags: newsletter

I thought this would be a fairly common need and was surprised not to find any tutorials on it from some quick searches I did.

I was looking for a way to enable a site admin to subscribe a customer to the newsletter when placing an order through the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still assuming there's probably a native way to do this in Magento but haven't found it yet.

The way I ended up solving it was by rewriting

```
Clean_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account::_prepareForm()
```

and

```
Clean_Sales_Model_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create::_prepareCustomer()
```

Both of the rewrites can be done pretty cleanly by relying on the parent method and then just dropping in the logic after that.

At first I thought I could get away with using a Customer Attribute (if you're on Enterprise) called `is_subscribed`, but it's not a very clean solution.  It will subscribe the customer but it won't respect the newsletter subscriber's state for subsequent orders and generally won't be sync'd with the subscriber status.